# software does not want to update

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. 
Every time I try to update my software/ check for updates I receive the following message: "**failed to update firmware due to network or server problem. Try software update via settings>software update> Update, or try using PC Kies later**"

I have tried everything but it still gives me the same messages.
sometimes I don't even try to update my software and I will receive the same message out of the blue.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: That is dependant on your carrier and country you are based in. Alternative would be to use multiloader and download the latest firmware from [samfirmware](http://samfirmware.com), this requires *user registration* to download the latest.. :)